# How do I get a 20% ratio of sodium bisulfate with 1 gallon water?

Tags: aqueous-solution, concentration

How many lbs do I add to 1 gallon of water to get a 20% sodium bisulfate ratio? I am in the middle of anodizing some aluminum.... I just threw the whole 3 lbs in... hopefully it works... I ended up doing a 2 gallon to 3 lb ratio... is this good? It is very cloudy looking

Picture for proof this is not a homework question like the person in the comments below wrongly assumed vs just helping with the question:

[image]

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

Comment: actually no its not... i am in the middle of anodizing some aluminum and want to know now... I just ended up throwing the whole 3 pounds in... hopefully it works

Comment: What percentage you need to make? Is it $w/w$ or $w/v$?

Comment: I do not know... they say just a 20% solution of sodium bi-sulfate to anodize (this method is suppose to be safer than using acid) http://www.observationsblog.com/sciencetechnologyexperiments/anodizing-and-dying-aluminum-without-battery-acid I suck at this math type stuff... I am literally sitting over here with a bucket full of this stuff waiting to make sure I got it right... bout to say F' it and try it anyway and see what happens.

Comment: @Jeff the idea of a homework question on the site is essentially a question where you state a problem without context and/or the efforts you have made to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't something that requires 0.1% precision.

The link says "40 grams of sodium bisulfate in 160 ml of tap water."

160 ml of tap water is very close to 160 grams.

A gallon of water is reasonable close to 4 liters or 4000 grams.

$\dfrac{4000}{160} = 25$

$25 \times 40 \text{ grams}= 1000 \text{ grams} \approx 2.2 \text{ lbs/(gallon of water)}$